# How to Access Local JavaScript File from a Cloud Functions HTML File?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to simply access a JavaScript file from within an HTML file using the script src attribute, and I have been unable to do so. Both files are in my functions folder.

I have the following Cloud Function index.js file in my functions folder:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const db = require('./admin');
var viewerApp = require('./viewerApp');

exports.view = functions.https.onRequest(viewerApp);
```

the viewApp.js file looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require('fs');
const viewerApp = express();

module.exports = 
  viewerApp.get('/:collection_name/:id', (req, res) => 
    {
      var viewerHTML = fs.readFileSync('./viewerApp.html').toString();
      var id = req.params.id;
      var collection_name = req.params.collection_name;
      var rendered_HTML = eval(viewerHTML);
      res.send(rendered_HTML);
    }
  )
```

You will notice the eval(viewerHTML) statement, which refers to a separate html file called viewerApp.html, which basically contains a template literal and looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
  </html>
```

(if someone has a better suggestion for separating the HTML into a separate file while being able to use ${variables} that would be helpful as well, as eval() is not ideal and perhaps is part of what is causing my problem)

The above works fine, except that I cannot figure out how to reference a JavaScript file located in the same functions folder, which means I would need to include all my JavaScript in the viewerApp.html file, which will be a mess.

I have tried all these possibilities in the viewerApp.html file (to try and refer to a JavaScript file called test.js):

```
<script src="./test.js"></script>
<script src="/test.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script src=test.js></script>
```

All of the above yield the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <       test.js:2
```

(I get the same error if I try and refer to a filename that doesn't exist so I suspect a problem in the file path or limitation on the ability to access the local file system)

I don't know what to make of the error being related to a < character, as the content of test.js is simply:

```
console.log("logging happened");
```

Any assistance would be MUCH appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: You tagged this with google-cloud-firestore, and mentioned Firestore in the title, but I don't really see it involved in your problem description.

Comment: Good point. I suppose I thought Cloud Functions were more directly tied to Cloud Firestore but upon review I see that Cloud Functions is a "[Google Cloud Platform product" on its own](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/)".

Comment: Yes, the only way Cloud Functions and Cloud Firestore cross over is when writing Firestore triggers.  Which is not what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the end was that I did not initialize and configure firebase hosting which seems to be what allows html/js/css and other static files to be accessible in HTML returned from the cloud function. Once I did that and setup the public folder, I was able to refer to the test.js file by putting it in the public folder. That plus addition tweaks to the rewrite section of the firebase.json file, and I was all set. Following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8) helped a lot and contains all the required steps.